# Ubuntu 20.04 Server firewall

Tags: firewall, ufw, port-forwarding

if I type `ufw status verbos` my system returns `status: inactive`; but when I was scanning my ports for a specific port with nmap, it returned a closed state for my port.

What else besides the firewall can block ports on this version of Ubuntu / how would I go about opening ports when ufw is inactive?

I am new to ufw, so if it has to do with ufw, you may need to provide some additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no special trick, no secret. Just make sure that you are not getting your terms mixed up.

1. A port that is *open* means that:

   - The firewall is not blocking packets to that port, and
   - An application has bound to that port, and is (probably) listening.
2. A port that is *closed* means that:

   - The firewall is not blocking packets to that port, and
   - An application has bound to that port.
3. A port that is *blocked* means that:

   - The firewall is blocking packets to that port.

Ubuntu's firewall does no blocking by default (Ubuntu has no vulnerable services listening). If a port is *closed*, it means that no application is listening on that port.

If you expected an application to be listening, then it's time for you to investigate why that application did not bind to the expected port and is not listening.

Comment: That answers my question then, I was confusing closed with blocked.  That makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ufw enable
```

[ufw](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) is merely a frontend to configure and view the status of netfilter.